# Given two square matrices $A$ and $B$, is $(AB)^2 = A^2B^2$ true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

I tried with a counter example and it came out that this claim is false.

I took a matrix 
$$
  A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2 & 1\\
   3 & 2\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

and a matrix

$$
  B=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 3\\
   4 & 1\\
  \end{array} } \right].
$$

I first calculated $$AB$$

and I got:

$$
  AB=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   6 & 7\\
   11 & 11\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

and then I calculated $$AB \times AB$$ that is same as $$(AB)^2$$
and I got:
$$
  (AB)^2=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   85 & 119\\
   187 & 198\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

then I calculated $$A \times A$$ that is the same as $$A^2$$ and I got
$$
  A^2=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   7 & 4\\
   12 & 13\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

and after I calculated $$B^2$$

$$
  B^2=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   13 & 6\\
   8 & 13\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

and at the end I calculated $$A^2B^2$$ and I got:

$$
  A^2B^2=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   123 & 94\\
   250 & 241\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

so I am deducing that the claim at the beginning is false, so
$$(AB)^2 \neq A^2B^2$$

Is this right?

Comment: One small comment, the first entry in $(AB)^2$ should be $113$ not $85$.

Comment: @wgrenard Thank you very much, you are right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have correctly constructed a counterexample to the proposition. Nice job!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming , $A$ and $B$ are invertible, we have $$(AB)^2=A^2B^2$$ if and only if $$ABAB=AABB$$ if and only if $$BA=AB$$ which is not true in general.

Answer (score 4):

In general, $AB \neq BA$, so $(AB)^2 = ABAB = A(BA)B \neq A(AB)B = A^2B^2.$

Answer (score 1):

It is true if the matrices commute:
$$ A^2B^2-(AB)^2 = AABB-ABAB = A(AB-BA)B, $$
so this is zero if $AB=BA$. Of course, it could also be true if the whole product is zero while the individual factors are not. But your counterexample does show it is not true in general.